# escaping characters in apache vhost - osx

Tags: php, apache

Simple apache question -

How do I escape the following folder name to allow apache to understand it?

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName calgary-ng-wrapper.lvh.me
    DocumentRoot /Users/myname/workspaces/mysite/week-two-09232011 (branch)
    <Directory "/Users/myname/workspaces/mysite/week-two-09232011 (branch)">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I thought backslashes would work, but they seem not to.

---

EDIT to clarify question -

The problem is with this line - 
    DocumentRoot /Users/myname/workspaces/mysite/week-two-09232011 (branch)

I need apache to recognise the bracketes

Comment: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/urlencode/Encode.aspx

Comment: I think problem is here with ( ).

Comment: I may not have been clear in my question - the problem is definitely with () but I can't change the folder name.

Comment: Use the link I provided to turn the string into a proper URLencoded URL.

Comment: Pekka, I've tried but Apache tells me that the folder does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also put the first occurance of the path within quotes:

```
DocumentRoot "/Users/myname/workspaces/mysite/week-two-09232011 (branch)"
```